# Solving recurrences of form $x_{n+1} = ax_n+\frac{b}{x_n}$?

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Given the recurrence:
$$x_{n+1} = ax_n+\frac{b}{x_n}$$
How do I determine the general solution? Is it possible to solve by generating functions? If I could have a small hint that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: There is not going to be a general solution. Just the asymptotics, maybe.

Comment: Nah, there is going to be a solution. Or I will make one.

Comment: I like your attitude. As to the solution, let's wait for some third opinion.

Comment: For $\,a\neq 1\,$ it's enough to discuss the special case $\,\displaystyle z_{n+1} = az_n+\frac{1-a}{z_n}\,$ because with $\,\displaystyle z_n:=x_n/\sqrt{\frac{b}{1-a}}\,$ for all $\,n\,$ one gets the initial recurrence.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Similar to [Does this recurrence have a closed form limit $x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{a}{3^{2n+1}x_n}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1902124),

Let $x_n=ku_n$ ,

Then $ku_{n+1}=aku_n+\dfrac{b}{ku_n}$

$u_{n+1}=au_n+\dfrac{b}{k^2u_n}$

$u_{n+1}=a\left(u_n+\dfrac{b}{ak^2u_n}\right)$

Case $1$: $ab>0$

Take $k=\dfrac{\sqrt b}{\sqrt a}$ , the recurrence becomes

$u_{n+1}=a\left(u_n+\dfrac{1}{u_n}\right)$

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see how this is any easier than the original

Comment: @mtheorylord, it has only one parameter, $a$.